# value in angular doesn't display

Tags: angular, placeholder, ngmodel

I have a problem with the value of one input in a bootstrap modal in angular.

I have `ngModel` on a variable of type `ngbDateStruct` (for a date picker) but I want replace the placeholder with the current date from my array on my service like the other camps population area and name.

Modal HTML

```html
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modifica Paese</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="tableService.close()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="countryName">Nome Paese</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryName" name="countryName"
          [(ngModel)]="tableService.country_Copia.name" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="countryArea">Area</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="countryArea" name="countryArea"
          [(ngModel)]="tableService.country_Copia.area">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="countryPopulation">Popolazione</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryPopulation" name="countryPopulation"
          [(ngModel)]="tableService.country_Copia.population ">
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <label for="countryPopulation">Data Censimento</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input readonly class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker
            #d="ngbDatepicker" />
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary bi bi-calendar3" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="salva_modale()">Salva</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="tableService.close()">Chiudi</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Modal TS

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { TableServiceService } from '../table-service.service';
import { NgbDateStruct, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-component',
  templateUrl: './modal-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-component.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public tableService: TableServiceService, private modalService: NgbModal, public decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {
   
  }
  model!: NgbDateStruct;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.model = this.tableService.country_Copia.date;
  }
 
  selectedDate: NgbDateStruct | undefined;
  
  openDatePicker(content: any) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { centered: true });
  }

  salva_modale() {
    this.tableService.salva_modale_service(this.model, this.tableService.country_Copia.area, this.tableService.country_Copia.population);
  }

  close() {
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
  }
}
```

Service TS

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe, formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { NgbDateStruct, NgbModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TableServiceService {
  modalRef!: NgbModalRef;
  country_Copia: any = {};
  country_modificato = {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    area: '',
    population: '',
    date: ''
  };
  model!: NgbDateStruct;
  countries_service_array: any[] = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Russia',
      flag: 'f/f3/Flag_of_Russia.svg',
      area: 17075200,
      population: 146989754,
      date: ""
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Canada',
      flag: 'c/cf/Flag_of_Canada.svg',
      area: 9976140,
      population: 36624199,
      date: ""
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'United States',
      flag: 'a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg',
      area: 9629091,
      population: 324459463,
      date: ""
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'China',
      flag: 'f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg',
      area: 9596960,
      population: 1409517397,
      date: ""
    },
  ];

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe, private ngbModal: NgbModal, private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    this.generateRandomDates();
   
  }

  modifica(countryId: number, country: any): void {
    const index = this.countries_service_array.findIndex(country => country.id === countryId);
    if (index !== -1) {
      country = this.countries_service_array[index];
      this.country_Copia = { ...country };
      this.country_modificato = country;
      
    }
  }
  openModal(content: any) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(content);
  }


  close() {
    this.ngbModal.dismissAll();
  }

  generateRandomDates(): void {
    const start = new Date(2000, 0, 1).getTime();
    const end = new Date().getTime();
    this.countries_service_array.forEach(country => {
      const randomTimestamp = Math.random() * (end - start) + start;
      const randomDate = new Date(randomTimestamp);
      const timezoneOffset = randomDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
      const localDate = new Date(randomDate.getTime() - timezoneOffset);
      country.date = localDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
      country.date = this.datePipe.transform(localDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
    });
  }


  salva_modale_service(model: NgbDateStruct, area: number, population: number): void {
    const index = this.countries_service_array.findIndex(c => c.id === this.country_modificato.id);
    if (index !== -1) {
      if (isNaN(area) || isNaN(population)) {
        alert('Inserire solamente numeri nei campi area e popolazione');
        this.close();
        return;
      }
      if (model === undefined) {
        alert('Inserire una data valida');
        return;
      }
      const dateString = formatDate(new Date(model.year, model.month - 1, model.day), 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'en-US');
      this.countries_service_array[index].date = dateString;
      this.countries_service_array[index].area = area;
      this.countries_service_array[index].population = population;
    }
    this.close();
  }
}
```

I've tried for too much time receiving only a frustration for a stupid error

Comment: You have shown your code but have not said what the error is. What is not working in this?

Comment: i want to replace the placeholder in data censimento input whit a date in my array that s situated in the service.
like this  [value]="tableService.country_Copia.population ", but the ngmodel cover the value,and i can't cancel the variable model in the ngmodel because my date picker dont works after that

Comment: So you want a custom placeholder value, and you want the data, but you want to show the placeholder instead of the data until someone uses the datepicker?

Comment: yes i want the data in the variabile date in the input of date till someone click on a date  on the datepicker

Comment: It seems you want to do something a little bit strange, so my thought is that you will need to do something strange to make this happen. Here's what I would try and do: Set up the date picker and hide it. Now set up a dummy input with what you want. When it is clicked, switch them out. You may need to set focus on the datepicker or manually trigger it to make this feel seamless

Comment: yes but how? sincerely i m new to angular i dont know how i can replace the value of model at start of ng serve and how i can replace another time the value of model when user click on a date in the date picker

Answer (score 0):

Angular is hard to demo on StackOverflow, but I am building off of my comment above.  My suggestion is to make a "dummy" input that shows the initial/placeholder value you want and then switch that out with the real datepicker as soon as the user begins to interact with it.

This is all just example code that is untested, just to give you an idea of how this might be done by what I tried to describe. This may not be perfect.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="countryPopulation">Data Censimento</label>

  <div class="input-group" *ngIf="showDummyDatepicker">
    <input readonly class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
           [value]="dummyValue" (click)="switchToRealDatepicker()" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary bi bi-calendar3" 
            (click)="switchToRealDatepicker()"></button>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group" *ngIf="!showDummyDatepicker">
    <input readonly class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp"
           [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary bi bi-calendar3" 
            (click)="d.toggle()"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```ts
//Get the datepicker input element from the HTML template
@ViewChild('d') private datepicker: ElementRef<HTMLElement> | undefined;

showDummyDatepicker = false;
dummyValue = "whatever";

switchToRealDatepicker(): void {
  this.showDummyDatepicker = true;

  //a delay might be needed for the datepicker element to appear
  setTimeout(()=>{
    //show the datepicker on the real element
    this.datepicker.toggle();
  });
}
```